# Express POST request values not received

Tags: html, node.js, express

I'm trying to make a simple registration page using Express but when I attempt to access the value of an input from the HTML form, I get `undefined`.

**app.js:**

```js
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();
const handlebars = require('express-handlebars');

const { json } = require('express');
var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;


var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use( bodyParser.json() );       
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
})); 

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));


app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')))
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, "views"));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');


app.get('/', (req,res)=>{
    res.render('index');
})
app.get('/register', (req,res)=>{
    res.render('register');
})

app.post('/register',(req,res)=>{
    const name = req.body.name;
    console.log(req.body.name);
    res.render('index');
})

app.listen(port, ()=>{
    console.log(`Server is running at port ${port}`);
})
```

**register.hbs:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css">
    <title>Registration Website</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome to our Registration page</h1>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="form-box">
            <form action="/register" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter Your name" autocomplete="off">
                <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter Your email" autocomplete="off">
                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter password" autocomplete="off">
                <input type="password" name="cpassword" placeholder="Confirm your password" autocomplete="off">

                <button type="submit" name="submit">Register</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My file structure:

[image: image of file structure]

Comment: I may be wrong, though try removing `enctype='multipart/formdata'` in your `<form>`. Let me know if it works and I will post an answer detailing an explanation.

Comment: Yes it's works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<form>` element is set to send POST requests encoded with `multipart/form-data`, therefore the payload received with Express cannot simply fetch the values from the `req.body` element. The `multipart/form-data` encoding is used for encoding and sending files,
so in a normal form such as this, it is unrequired.

By default, if the `enctype` property is not provided, `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is used and this allows your POST payload to be accessed through the request body in Express.

```html
<form action="/register" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

```js
app.post("/register", (req, res) => {
    const name = req.body.name; // Fetches the 'name' input's value.
    ...
});
```